# Run Maven archetype "quickstart" in Java 10?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3, java-10

When I create a new IntelliJ 2018.1 project from the Maven archetype `maven-archetype-quickstart` version 1.3 using Oracle 10.0.1 on macOS Sierra, I get this error when doing a Maven `install`.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test (default-test) on project h2e2: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test failed.: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]

I am running this directly after creating the new project. I am writing *no* code. I can run the default line:

```
    public static void main( String[] args ) { System.out.println( "Hello World!" ); }
```

…by choosing `Run 'App.main()'` from the context menu clicked in the code editor. That works, but the Maven `install` fails.

Executing `clean` and `install` in the Maven pane of IntelliJ does not solve the problem.

[image]

If I switch IntelliJ `File` > `Project Structure` > `Project` > `Project SDK` > from 10.0.1 to 1.8.0_171 (and set `Project language level` to `8 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.`), then the Maven `install` succeeds.

> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
>
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

If I return that setting to Java 10, the Maven `install` fails again, with same error.

I am running external Maven 3.5.3 rather than IntelliJ’s bundled older version, for no particular reason.

My older existing projects based on Java 8 have no problem. My only problem is trying to create new Maven-based `quickstart` projects using Java 10.

Comment: Does it fail with `2.21.0` of surefire as well?

Comment: @nullpointer I don’t know anything about surefire. I just want a very simple no-frills Maven-based project. I thought that was the purpose of the `quickstart` archetype.

Comment: Could you try setting this property in your pom.xml:
`<maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.21.0</maven-surefire-plugin.version>`

Also what is your java-version in the pom? The archetype defaults to 1.7...
`    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>`
`    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>`

Is maven also using the Java 10 JDK? You can check this by running `mvn -X clean`

Comment: @Maarten How does one run `mvn -X clean` within the IntelliJ IDE? Is it possible to pass arguments like `-X` to the Lifecycle items such as `clean` in the Maven pane of IntelliJ?

Comment: For Java 10 you have to upgrade surefire/failsafe plugin to 2.21.0 ....

Comment: @BasilBourque, I would do that commandline. That is much easier. You could also create a run configuration from your lifecycle 'clean' step and add the -X to the 'Command line'-field in that run configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Later version of `maven-surefire-plugin`

It seems the archetype is not yet updated for Java 10.

According to this blog post: http://joshlong.com/jl/blogPost/java-10.html, you can do the following to get it up and running...

> .... I want to use Java 10, though, so I opened the pom.xml file and
>   changed the java.version property value to be 10. The Maven surefire
>   plugin broke the build next; it was complaining about not being able
>   to parse the version of the JDK. I overrode the version by redefining
>   the property for the plugin's version:
>   2.21.0.

The important part here is I think updating to the higher version of surefire, as mentioned in the comments. As of 2018-10, the [current version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin) is `2.22.1`.

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Indeed, changing the surefire version to `2.21.0` allows the Maven lifecycle item `install` to complete successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Maarten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50169954/642706) is correct and crucial.

## Set compiler source/target to `10`

In addition to that Answer’s solution updating the version `maven-surefire-plugin`, to run that Maven "Quickstart" archetype based project on Java 10, you will need to change the POM file to **indicate Java 10 is to be used by the compiler**.

Change this:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

to replace the pair of `1.7` occurrences to `10`:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>10</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>10</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```